# Declare variables in xml

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot

i define spring.application.name in spring boot properties,
wrote $ {spring.application.name:-} in logback.xml, but it says spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED.
Do you know why?

How do I use something like "hostname" in xml ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%5p [${spring.zipkin.service.name:${spring.application.name:-}},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa %d{HH:mm} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="example.logback.level.grandparents" level="TRACE"/>
    <logger name="example.logback.level.grandparents.parents.children" level="INFO"/>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

my 'application.properties'

```
spring.application.name=elasticsearch-monitering
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=foo
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#elasticsearch server info
server.elasticsearch.host=my.i.p
server.elasticsearch.port=9200
```

Comment: show us your `logback.xml`

Comment: I added it. :) How do I change the part? 
$ {spring.zipkin.service.name: $ {spring.application.name:-}}

Comment: also show `ur application.properties`

Comment: I added it. :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 3 classes

See example below:

**application.properties**

```
logback.appender.FILE-AUDIT.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, GMT+8} - %msg%n
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <configuration>
             ..........
          <springProperty name="fileAppenderPattern" source="logback.appender.FILE-AUDIT.ConversionPattern"/>
             ..........
          <include resource="logback-appender-file.xml"/>
            ..........
      </configuration>
```

**logback-appender-file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>${fileAppenderPattern}</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="example.logback.level.grandparents" level="TRACE"/>
    <logger name="example.logback.level.grandparents.parents.children" level="INFO"/>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```